# Mentioning Products of Companies in Technical Paper?

Tags: publications

I am writing a technical paper for my college project. This is my first time so I don't have much experience in this arena.
I am writing about a philosophy used by Mechanical Engineers while designing a product. Now there is a situation where I have to mention a product and the company whose product it is.
I am saying this by:

```
... so popular that it has been incorporated by ABC Company in their XYZ Product suite ...
```

Now I want to ask whether I should mention that:

```
ABC & XYZ are registered trademark of ABC Inc.
```

If yes then where and in what format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to mention the trademarks in a technical paper, although you could certainly cite their website if it talks about the product.

I generally cite anything that I think the reader could get more information about that is pertinent to the topic.  That said, a paper isn't a web page, and you shouldn't litter it with gratuitous cites.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned, then you can say:

`... so popular that it has been incorporated by ABC Company(R) in their XYZ(TM) Product suite ...`

with appropriate glyphs for "registered" and "trademark".

But that said, I don't think it's strictly necessary to mention trademarks unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

(An example of a comeppling reason to do so would be if you had to run the paper by the company's lawyers first and they want you to refer to the product in a specific way. If so then in the best interest of collaboration you should do what their lawyers say.)